# Transport Large Directory Structure to AWS EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, data-transfer

I need to transport just less than 6 TB of data from one Windows Server 2008 R2 (located locally) to a second instance on a customer AWS EC2 instance. The customer configuration does not allow Device Redirection so I am unable to remotely mount the directory to the EC2 instance. Is WebDAV an option here? Will it support transporting that volume of data?

Comment: Device redirection isn't the same as mounting network drives. It bypasses network security and makes local devices visible on the remote host. This is why it is often disabled. Try normal network methods in both directions (access local network resource from remote host, access resource on remote host from local machine).

Comment: where's a good place to start? Cifs? FTP? Can CIFS work over open internet without a VPN?

Comment: If your only connecting using remote desktop no. You need a VPN to do normal network access.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/527914/transport-large-directory-structure-to-aws-ec2